# difference between () and [] in terms of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

What is difference between char* p = new char and char* p = new char[100] and char* p = new char(200), how it is reflected in pointer arithmetic?

Comment: what is difference between char* p = new char and char* p = new char[100] and char* p = new char(200), how it is reflected in pointer arithmetic.

Comment: "Also `p[99] = 'a';`" - that has undefined behaviour... you're attempting to write `a` to memory 99 bytes past the allocated memory at `*p`... your program do anything, including limp along with no, subtle or overt error(s) in its data and/or processing and crash at any time.

Comment: but it did not crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* p = new char
```

initializes a `char*` to a dynamically allocated a single, uninitialized char.

```
char* p = new char[100]
```

initializes a `char*` to a point to the first element of a dynamically allocated array of 200 uninitialized chars.

```
char* p = new char(200)
```

initializes a `char*` to a dynamically allocated a single char, initialized with the value `200` (which may or may not overflow depending on the number of bits and signedness of `char` on your platform.)